# Ruby regex to capture part of content between two strings

Tags: regex, ruby

With ruby `gsub()`, in string `<code>balabala or blank \n another balabala or blank</code>`, replacing all `\n` inside `<code>...</code>` block into `<br>`, but do nothing to the content outside `<code>...</code>`.

I tried `/<code>.*(\\n?).*<\/code>/` but not working:

```rb
html = '<pre>do \n nothing<code>line \n break</code></pre>'

html = html.gsub(/<code>.*(\\n?).*<\/code>/) { "<br>" }

print html

# actual result: <pre>do \n nothing<br></pre>

# expect result: <pre>do \n nothing<code>line <br> break</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match all substrings between `<code>` and `</code>` and replace all `\n` with `<br>`  in those matches only:

```
html = html.gsub(/<code>.*?<\/code>/m) { $~[0].gsub('\n', '<br>') }
```